# Kendo Splitter inside Kendo TabStrip with MVVM init

Tags: jquery, kendo-ui, kendo-ui-splitter, kendo-tabstrip

I have a page with a Kendo splitter inside a Kendo tabstrip and they are instantiated using the kendo.init method.  There are two tabs and the splitter control is in the second tab.  When I click on the second tab, the splitter control has not been initialised correctly.  The splitter's divider is not the correct height.

I have put together a sample page that demonstrates this behaviour:

HTML:

```
<div id="testContainer">
    <div 
        id="testTabStrip"
        data-role="tabstrip">
        <ul>
            <li class="k-state-active">Tab1</li>
            <li>Tab2</li>
        </ul>
        <div>
            <div id="tab1-content">
                Tab One Content
            </div>
        </div>
        <div>
            <div id="tab2-content">
                <div data-role="splitter"
                    data-panes="[
                        { collapsible: true, size: '300px' },
                        { collapsible: true }
                    ]" 
                    style="min-height:700px">
                    <div id="Left-Pane">
                        Left Pane Content
                    </div>
                    <div id="Right-Pane">
                        Right Pane Content
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

JavaScript:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    kendo.init($('#testContainer'));
    $('#testTabStrip').bind('select', function (e) {
        setTimeout(function () {
            $(e.contentElement).find(".k-splitter").each(function () {
                $(this).data("kendoSplitter").trigger("resize");
            },300);
        });
    });
});
```

Here is a fiddle of the above code: http://jsfiddle.net/codeowl/2nq5z/3/

You can see in this example that I have tried to implement a workaround I found on the Web to trigger the resize event of the splitter on the select event of the tabstrip. However, this has not worked.

How can I resolve this issue?

Thanks for your time,

Regards,

Scott

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The approach to resizing has changed in the 2014 Q1 release; you should no longer call `widget.trigger("resize")`. Instead, use [`kendo.resize()`](http://docs.telerik.com/kendo-ui/api/framework/kendo#methods-resize); also, you should bind to the `activate` event so `e.contentElement` is visible when your handler is called; that way you don't need the `setTimeout`:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    kendo.init($('#testContainer'));
    var tabStrip = $('#testTabStrip').data("kendoTabStrip");

    tabStrip.bind('activate', function (e) {
        kendo.resize($(e.contentElement));
    });
});
```

(updated [demo](http://jsfiddle.net/lhoeppner/2nq5z/5/))